# ng-grid/ui-grid celltemplate on click causes row to be selected.

Tags: ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

When I use celltemplate for ahref link, once the link is clicked the row highlights because i have RowSelection enabled...but i dont want the row to highlight when the link is clicked..only if the row is clicked anywhere but the link.

Also in my below example picture, how do I remove the little arrow so no Menuitems can be displayed for that column?

Code:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    showFooter: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    columnDefs: [
    { field:'date', displayName: 'Date', width: 200, aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.count  },
    { field:'notes', displayName: 'Notes', width: 65, enableFiltering: false, enableSorting: false, enableHiding: false, cellTemplate:'<a href="#" ng-click="getExternalScopes().showMe(row.entity[col.field])">View</a>' }
    ],
    data: data
}
```

Pic:
[image]

Comment: Can you give a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/)( or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/), [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/)...etc)? It's helpful for solve your question.

Comment: Please clarify: ng-grid or ui-grid? The differences are not so minor as it seems on a first look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible answer to ui-grid (which is not ng-grid anymore!).

The cell template for a button that does not select the row is:

```
cellTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();getExternalScopes().showMe(row)">Click Me</button>'
```

Note the `$event.stopPropagation()` in the ng-click directive. This will hinder the click to reach the underlying functions of the rowTemplate.
(Note also that I didn't found another way to pass a click event to the controller than by using externalScopes. I'm sure there is a better way but ui-grid is still beta and I'm also pretty new to it)

Second part of your question: Use this headCellTemplate

```
var headCelltpl = '<div ng-class="{ \'sortable\': sortable }">' +
  '<div class="ui-grid-vertical-bar">&nbsp;</div>' +
  '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" col-index="renderIndex">' +
  '{{ col.displayName CUSTOM_FILTERS }}' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';
```

and add it to the respective columns in your columnDefs.

```
headerCellTemplate: headCelltpl
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nm0dvF0xvimLzyVhgj5g?p=preview) with everything included.

Please don't tell me you meant ng-grid:-)

Comment: Thanks for the row highlight fix.. The second question (down arrow) can be disabled by using this in the ColumnDef: enableColumnMenu: false   -- maybe you want to update your answer but it's upto you:) thanks again

Comment: Nah, your answer regarding the menu is way better. There is a lot to read in the new manuals :-/ Thanks for this useful input!

Answer (score 0):

The simple [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244455/how-to-highlight-the-current-row-when-cell-template-button-is-clicked-in-anguala/39246087) is change the `row.setSelected` to `false`

```
cellTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.deSelectRow(row)">Click Me</button>'

$scope.deSelectRow = function(row) {
     row.setSelected(false);
  };
```