# How to highlight the current row when cell template button is clicked in angualar UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have enabled `ui-grid-selection` on grid.As a result that when row is selected it will be get highlighted but my requirement is that i want to highlight the row only when the cell template button is clicked.Please let me know how to do this.

[Code Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/FtAEaUjDVXmo1CuSgxHN?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to find a way to do that.Here is the [answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/FtAEaUjDVXmo1CuSgxHN?p=preview).

What i did was,

1. In grid option changed `enableRowSelection: false`.
2. Add a function to cell template button.

**Button Cell Template**

```
<div><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="grid.appScope.selectRow(row)">O</button></div>
```

3. Implement a function to select given row obj.

   `$scope.selectRow = function(row) {
       row.setSelected(true);
     };`

if you want to unselect the selected row when the template button is clicked again you can use `row.isSelected`this will return boolean value.Here is the updated function code snippet.

```
$scope.selectRow = function(row) {
       if(row.isSelected!=true){
         //Select the row
         row.setSelected(true)
       }else{
          row.setSelected(false)
       }
  };
```

Comment: ok..but one issue I found..(i don't know if that is a issue or your requirement) once a row is selected it is not deselecting even though you select some other row.